# adding libraries manually to Xcode project

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

I am trying to add a library "WeScan" to my Xcode project manually. I just downloaded the source file from GitHub and by drag and drop, added that we scan folder to my project. Then I tried to import that, but it is giving an error like

> No such module 'WeScan'

And also this library is not adding with linkbinarywithlibraries.If anyone help's me would be great.Thanks in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wD25b.png)

Answer (score 5):

Notice the blue color of the WeScan folder in your project navigator. This tells you that you have added this folder as a *folder reference*. You can't do that with code files. Delete the WeScan folder from the project navigator and drag it in from the Finder again, and this time make it a *group*. Now the code files will be part of your project.

Comment: I have changed the screen shot.added updated screen.Even though ,it's throwing  the same error